# Reactjs component.setProps() alternative, how to send variable to detached element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using things like:

```
var MUSIC = React.renderComponent( Music({ }), document.getElementById("music-div"))
```

to later in the script, in an independent element (so not parent of `MUSIC`) do:

```
MUSIC.setProps({ url: 'http://...' })
```

to send a song to de music player, which is detached from the rest, so it does not accidentally gets refreshed by react, because it was programmatically generated (wavesurferjs)

Fine, however, the recent few updates (.11.x) have apparently deprecated that. I do understand where they are coming from, it fits the whole React logic.

However, how will we now ever programmatically modify state/props from outside? Even when I want to talk directly to the parent, which should be allowed.

The changelog tells me in this case the `MUSIC` variable would have become a `descriptor`, however, in consoles out the exact same object as far as I can tell. And the documentation says nothing about this `descriptor` and even less about alternative possibilities.

(http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#descriptors)

So, if I have two `divs`

```
<div id="main-div"> <button></button></div>
<div id="music-div"> </div>
```

And want to keep them separate, how would I go about giving two parallel parents each-other props?
I don't want to put both in one react div, which would not even solve my problem, because, how would the `button` in `main-div` give the props to music-div?

Or would their conceived alternative be to just create a new instance on that `id` and *hope* it diffs to 0?

*The update states*:

> "You could store that reference and then call functions on it (eg
>   component.setProps(...)). This no longer works."

However, that still does work, with (0.11.1) so I don't understand what they are talking about?

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood the change: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/8928067

Answer (score 2):

You've got several options.

1. Wrap both `main-div` and `music-div` with an "Application" component. Pass a handler down that changes its state so the div's are re-rendered.
2. Use an event bus to dispatch and listen to events. Basically a component exposes its private `setState/setProps()` methods to the event bus in a listener. The other component dispatches an event that triggers that listener.

Comment: +1. Both solutions seem appropriate but I prefer #1 to be in line with React's "components" paradigm and to better fit into the Flux architecture. If you do follow Flux, your event bus from #2 is implemented by the actions+dispatcher anyway.